# Iterating an array with pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have trouble understanding the concept of pointers with arrays.

Why does *(array+i) stand for? Is it creating a pointer? If so, how is it affecting the for loop? (I am a beginner in C)

```
int main() {

  int array[10] = {0, 1, 8, 2, 18, 3, 6, 2, 2, -4};

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)


  printf( "array[%d] = %d\n", i, *(array+i) );

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: re. code style, I recommend always using `{}` after the `for` to make the loop body obvious. And at the very least, you should indent the `printf` and place it on the following line after the `for`.

Comment: Next steps to learn: remove both occurrences of `10` from the code and figure out how to make the compiler count the elements for you.

Comment: #1:  `array` is equivalent to the address of the first element: `&array[0]`
#2:  `array+i` is equivalent to the address of the i-th element: `&array[i]`
#3:  `*(array+i)` is equivalent to the value at the i-th element: `array[i]`

Answer (score 3):

Adding `i` to a pointer value yields a pointer to the `i`'th *object* of the same type in a sequence.  Assuming the declarations

```
char  *cp = 0x8000;
short *sp = 0x8000;
long  *lp = 0x8000;
```

the following is true:

```
       char      char *    short     short *  long     long *
       ----      ------    -----     -------  ----     ------
       +---+               +---+              +---+
0x8000 |   | <-- cp        |   | <-- sp       |   | <-- lp
       +---+               |   |              |   |
0x8001 |   | <-- cp + 1    |   |              |   | 
       +---+               +---+              |   |
0x8002 |   | <-- cp + 2    |   | <-- sp + 1   |   |
       +---+               |   |              |   |
0x8003 |   | <-- cp + 3    |   |              |   |
       +---+               +---+              +---+
0x8004 |   | <-- cp + 4    |   | <-- sp + 2   |   | <-- lp + 1
       +---+               |   |              |   |
        ...                 ...                ...
```

`cp` points to a 1-byte object, `sp` points to a 2-byte object, and `lp` points to a 4-byte object, all starting at address`0x8000`.

The *expression* `cp + 1` has type `char *` and the value `0x8001` - it yields a pointer to the first `char` object following the object pointed to by `cp`.

The expression `sp + 1` has type `short *` and the value `0x8002` - it yields a pointer to the first `short` object following the object pointed to by `sp`.

And the expression `lp + 1` has type `long *` and the value `0x8004` - it yields a pointer to the first `long` object following the object pointed to by `lp`.

This is exactly how array subscripting works - the expression `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - given a pointer value specified by `a`, offset `i` elements (not bytes!) from that address and dereference the result.

Arrays are not pointers - array *expressions* "decay" to pointer values under most circumstances, precisely because of the semantics above.  When you write something like

```
a[i] = some_value;
```

the expression `a` is automatically *converted* from type "N-element array of `T`" to "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of `a`.  The exceptions to this rule are:

- when the array expression is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators;
- when the expression is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, like `char foo[] = "some string";`

Answer (score 0):

`*(array + i)` is equivalent to `array[i]`. The `array` itself is in many ways equivalent to a pointer to its first element, and pointer arithmetic works in units of the element type. The `*` dereferences the pointer, i.e., the result of the expression is the value at the `i`th element of `array`.

The `printf` is the body of the `for` loop (although misleadingly separated from it by blank lines). I'm guessing the extra four `*` are an attempt to bold the `*(array + i)` part, so the loop will print each element of the array: `array + 0` is the first element, and `*(array + 0)` is the same as `*array`, i.e., the value at that position. Then `array + 1` is the next one (recalling that the `1` is in units of the value/element type, here `int`), etc.

Comment: Mostly useless trivia: due to the equivalence of `*(array + i)` and `array[i]`, and commutativity of addition, they are also equivalent to `*(i + array)` and `i[array]`.

Comment: thank you!! so does that mean that for example instead of doing : printf("first element of this array is :  %d\n",array[0])) i can just do : printf("first element of this array is :  %d\n",*(array)); ( since *(array) is the same as array[0] )

Comment: @vivi2003 Yes, `*array` and `array[0]` refer to the same element.